# Trouble Sending Mail with Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

After making a GSuite account, I'm trying to send mail with Laravel and it simlpy won't work. It won't give me an error, it just says

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

No idea what's going on, I've tried changing my mail driver to SMTP, sendmail, mail

Tried changing my connection type to TLS and SSL, while also changing my port from 587 to 465

Here's my code for my Controller file that is sending the email

```
public function addStudent($Classroom) {
$emails = Request::all();
foreach($emails as $key) {
  if(!Auth::user()->where('email', $key)->first()) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $key;
    $user->name = "New User";
    $token = hash_hmac('sha256', str_random(40), config('app.key'));
    $user->password = $token;
    $user->save();

    $contactfirstname = $user->name;
    $contactemail = $user->email;


    DB::table('password_resets')->insert(['email' => $user->email, 'token' => $token, 'created_at' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);

    Mail::send('emails.welcomemail', ['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], function ($message) use ($contactfirstname, $contactemail) {
        $message->from('support@truthfultesting.com', 'Truthful Testing Admins');
        $message->to($contactemail, $contactfirstname)->subject('Welcome!');
    });
  } else {
    $user = Auth::user()->where('email', $key)->first();
  }

  $CA = new ClassroomAssociation();
  $CA->studentid = $user->id;
  $CA->classroomid = $Classroom->id;
  $CA->save();
 }
}
```

and for my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@mine.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and lastly my mail.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
|            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => 'myemail@myemail.com',
    'name' => 'Name',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'TLS'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('myemail@mine.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => env('password'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

I've read every single article on Google, as well as other resources, nothing is working. I've enabled access to my account for less secure apps, as well as I am currently using an app password

Thank you!
- Zach

Comment: It's very likely this is a problem with your server environment rather that your code. Also, don't tag your question as PHPMailer when you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating an app key here:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-sending-mail-swift-transportexception/replies/167048